# Three table MySQL join

Tags: mysql, join

Just when I thought I had figured out MySQL JoINS I run into this and it's doing my head in..
I've three tables for a shop:

```
tblProducts              tblProdCat                  tblCategory

prodID                   prodCatID                   categoryID
prodName                 categoryID                  categoryHidden
prodPrice                prodID                      categoryName
```

And what i'd like to do is create a query that finds products in a category that aren't hidden and I cannot get this to work.

At present all I can do is find the products in a category by joining the products table to the ProdCat table. As this query works I adapted it to this:

```
SELECT
    p.prodID, p.name, 
FROM
    tblProducts p
INNER JOIN
    tblProdCat pc
    ON 
    pc.prodID = p.prodID
inner JOIN
    tblCategory c
    ON
    c.categoryID = pc.categoryID
WHERE
    pc.categoryID = '7' AND 
    c.categoryHidden = '0'
```

Can anybody help me identify why this isn't working?

edit: fixed the name of prodID (it was a typo and not what is causing the issue)

Comment: post it in sqlfiddle the query seems  ok to me!!

Comment: FROM    tblProducts p
INNER JOIN tblProdCat pc
    ON pc.productID = p.prodID

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a column called `productID` on `tblProducts`

try

```
SELECT   p.prodID, p.name, 
FROM    tblProducts p
INNER JOIN tblProdCat pc
    ON pc.productID = p.prodID
inner JOIN tblCategory c
    ON c.categoryID = pc.categoryID
 WHERE   pc.categoryID = '7' AND c.categoryHidden = '0'
```

Also I can not tell from your schema but if `pc.categoryID` is a number then you do not need quotes.

Comment: Thanks for offering a suggestion but I can't get this to work.

Comment: Hmm, as someone suggested - post your stuff to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tblProducts as  p Inner join  tblProdCat as pc  Inner join tblCategory as c
where  pc.categoryID = '7' AND  c.categoryHidden = '0'
```

try this way

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this  (just dummy code )

```
select p.productID, p.name from 
tblProducts as p,tblCategory as c,tblProdCat as pc
where pc.categoryID = '7' AND c.categoryHidden = '0'
```